# Jenkins build is unable to checkout the code from SVN repository

Tags: jenkins, svn, tortoisesvn

I have jenkins job which is checking out the code from SVN repository and run the build but I am getting the multiple or different errors before its checking out the complete code.Please help me.

**Error:**

ERROR 1: svn: E155021: The path 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\Project1\branch-1.1' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155021: The path 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\Project\branch-1.1' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.

**Error 2:**

D:\jenkins\workspace\project\branch.svn\wc.db: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Please install [Tortoise SVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) (It has the cli interface) and add to Windows %PATH%.